# Why am I getting NAN and inf in output?

Tags: control-system, matlab

https://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/index.php?example=BallBeam&section=SystemModeling

Above link gives information about a ball & beam system.

I am trying to find the output response of a ball and beam system when a step is applied at the input.

My code is below:

```
clc
clear all
close all
m=0.111
R=0.015
g=-9.8
L=1.0
d=0.03
J=9.99*10^-6
num=[-m*g*d]
den=[L*((J/R.^2)+m) 0 0]
sys=tf(num,den)
step(sys)
stepinfo(sys)
```

When I run my code, I get output as shown in the attached snapshot.
Why am I getting NAN values in output as marked by the red boundary? And what is difference between NAN and inf?

Rather than plotting, when I store the result of `step(sys)` into `[y,t]` and then check each of them, I cannot find NAN or inf in either `y` or `t`, so why am I seeing them in output?

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to have nothing to do with Electrical Engineering.

Comment: I like the Activate Windows in the background!

Answer (score 3):

Because the system is unstable and if you execute **rlocus(sys)** you will see this

The reason you do not see Inf or NaN in the step data is because it runs over a finite time period (50seconds in this case) while the stepinfo solves the system equation to determine what these quantities are and because such a system potentially keeps rising at an infinite rate to infinity it can only return Inf or NaN

add a damping term to your 2nd order denominator